# Getting NullPointerException when getting the values from Properties file in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, properties

I am trying to get the properties(key:value pairs) from the properties file but I am getting Null Pointer Exception.

```
Properties prop;
@BeforeTest
public void beforeTest() throws IOException {
    prop=new Properties();
    FileInputStream objfile = new FileInputStream(
            "\\resources\\config.properties");
    prop.load(objfile);
    objfile.close();
}
```

The folder structure is

[image]

Comment: I saw it in com.test.com.test.keywordProperties folder ?

Comment: First thing is, rename the .Properties to .properties. Case sensitive matters here. Then, the properties files should be not under source. It should be under resource folder. Create resource folder and put the Config.properties file in it. You should not give absolute path like this. You have to use relative path as the file is inside your project itself

Comment: I updated to .Properties to .properties. Created the resource folder and shifted the config.properties to that resource folder still I am getting the NullPointerException.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the response

The issue is due to not declaring the valid **Access Modifier**(public static) to the variables that are extracted from the Properties file.
There is no problem in below points

- We can declare the properties file without using the resources folder
- we can declare the properties file as config.properties or config.property there is no need of any proper name
- We can get the file without using the format getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Config.properties") by using FIS

Answer (score 0):

You should load the properties as a resource, since they are part of your project. No need to use full file system path.

```
Properties prop = new Properties();

@BeforeTest
public void beforeTest() throws Exception {
  try (InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Config.properties") {
    prop.load(in);
  }  
}
```

Please note that it's not recommended to use the default Java package to avoid classpath clashes. Moving `Config.properties` to a named package would solve it.

Comment: I updated the path to relative path and updated the code to the code that you have suggested still I am getting the NullPointerException

Comment: To do that you should have the resources folder into the Java build path.

Comment: I have updated my code and screenshot could you please check and let me know

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to run in debug mode? Seems like your prop object is null. So there is nothing to load to. You need to create your Properties object inside your method. Move the constructor inside the method and then check.

```
@BeforeTest
    public void beforeTest() throws IOException {
        Properties prop=new Properties();
        FileInputStream objfile = new FileInputStream(
                "C:\\Users\\psailaja\\workspace\\TestPropertiesAndKeyword\\Config.properties");
        prop.load(objfile);
        objfile.close();
    }
```

Comment: I pushed the Properties obj into Method even I am getting nullPointerException

Comment: Please check my updated answer. Please take a note of the absolute path I have used. You need to use correct absolute path.

Comment: @sailaja.p Can you post the complete log of the NullPointer error trace? I would like to know what exactly is throwing the NullPointer. Also what is inside the properties file? Is it empty by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

While trying to get the `properties(key:value pairs)` from the *properties file* you are getting **Null Pointer Exception**. You have to take care of a couple of facts here as follows:

- Change the name of the property file from `config.properties` to **`config.property`**
- While you take help of *project location*, use the reference through **`.`**
- You need to initialize the `Properties` type of object **`prop`**.
- Here would be your working code:

  ```
  Properties prop;
  @BeforeTest
  public void beforeTest() throws IOException {

      File src = new File("./resources/config.property");
      FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(src);
      prop = new Properties();
      prop.load(fis);
      String propValue = prop.getProperty("propKey");
  }
  ```

Comment: I have updated the code the Properties prop;
 @BeforeTest
 public void beforeTest() throws IOException {
  File src=new File("./resources/config.property");
  FileInputStream objfile = new FileInputStream(src);
  prop=new Properties();
  prop.load(objfile);
  objfile.close();
     DriverPath = prop.getProperty("driverPath");
     
 } still I am getting the nullpointerexception

Comment: @sailaja.p What is the hurry to `objfile.close()`?